# boost serialization binary_oarchive crashes

Tags: c++, boost, archive, boost-serialization

First I am populating a structure which is quite big and have interrelations. and then I serialize that to a binary archive. Size of that structure depends on what data I feed to the program. I see the program taking ~2GB memory to build the structure which is expected and acceptable.

Then I start serializing the object. and I see program eating RAM while serializing. RAM usage growing till it reaches near 100%. swap usage is still 0 bytes.

and then the Application crashes. with a exception of `bad_alloc` on `new`

Why would serialization process take so much RAM and time ? and why would it crash while allocating memory when swap is empty ? the backtrace is too long to be pasted in full.

```
#0  0xb7fe1424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0xb7c6e941 in raise (sig=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:64
#2  0xb7c71e42 in abort () at abort.c:92
#3  0xb7e92055 in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#4  0xb7e8ff35 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#5  0xb7e8ff72 in std::terminate() () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#6  0xb7e900e1 in __cxa_throw () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#7  0xb7e90677 in operator new(unsigned int) () from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#8  0xb7f00a9f in boost::archive::detail::basic_oarchive_impl::save_pointer(boost::archive::detail::basic_oarchive&, void const*, boost::archive::detail::basic_pointer_oserializer const*) () from /usr/lib/libboost_serialization.so.1.42.0
#9  0xb7effb42 in boost::archive::detail::basic_oarchive::save_pointer(void const*, boost::archive::detail::basic_pointer_oserializer const*) () from /usr/lib/libboost_serialization.so.1.42.0
#10 0x082d052c in void boost::archive::detail::save_pointer_type<boost::archive::binary_oarchive>::non_polymorphic::save<gcl::NestedConnection<gcl::Section, gcl::NestedConnection<gcl::Paragraph, gcl::NestedConnection<gcl::Line, void> > > >(boost::archive::binary_oarchive&, gcl::NestedConnection<gcl::Section, gcl::NestedConnection<gcl::Paragraph, gcl::NestedConnection<gcl::Line, void> > >&) ()
#11 0x082d0472 in void boost::archive::detail::save_pointer_type<boost::archive::binary_oarchive>::save<gcl::NestedConnection<gcl::Section, gcl::NestedConnection<gcl::Paragraph, gcl::NestedConnection<gcl::Line, void> > > >(boost::archive::binary_oarchive&, gcl::NestedConnection<gcl::Section, gcl::NestedConnection<gcl::Paragraph, gcl::NestedConnection<gcl::Line, void> > > const&) ()

.......

#172 0x082a91d8 in boost::archive::detail::interface_oarchive<boost::archive::binary_oarchive>::operator<< <gcl::Collation const> (this=0xbfffe500, t=...) at /usr/include/boost/archive/detail/interface_oarchive.hpp:64
#173 0x082a6298 in boost::archive::detail::interface_oarchive<boost::archive::binary_oarchive>::operator&<gcl::Collation> (this=0xbfffe500, t=...) at /usr/include/boost/archive/detail/interface_oarchive.hpp:72
#174 0x0829bd63 in main (argc=4, argv=0xbffff3f4) at /home/neel/projects/app/main.cpp:93
```

- Program works properly When a smaller data is feeded to it.
- Using Linux 64bit with 32bit PAE kernel boost 1.42
- program was working without a crash few revision ago. I recently added some more bytes to the structures. may be then it was not reaching the end of RAM and now its reaching.

But why would new crash when there is enough swap ? why would serialization process take so much RAM ?

Comment: 174 lines is not too long (although indeed the trace is probably not very interesting). However, without a sense of the datastructures (preferrably: actual code) there is not a lot we can see, I guess...

Comment: What I am actually doing is parsing several text files in Structures and then doing N:N comparison between them. and getting connection objects. and I am serializing both. and its not a single line program. application is pretty huge and not possible to paste its code here.

Comment: Did you try any other archive type, i.e. text or XML?

Comment: No I'vent tried. but this is mostly binary data is it worth to give it a try ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that serialization process was taking extra memory, for its own house keeping works. and that was hitting the [`3GB Barrier`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3_GB_barrier)  To stop serialization process from taking extra memory I disabled object tracking [`BOOST_CLASS_TRACKING`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/serialization/doc/traits.html) and that fixed extra memory overhead.

Answer (score 1):

**Question: why would it crash while allocating memory when swap is empty ?**

The allocated object is too big to fit anywhere in the [virtual address space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space):

- The allocated object is humongous
- [virtual address space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) is too fragmented
- [virtual address space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) is all allocated

If your application is complied as a 32bits, the process [virtual address space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) is limited to 4Gb.

**Question: why would serialization process take so much RAM ?**

I have not found any evidence why.